# How to leave a cell blank when using IF plus AND/OR statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the following statement and its working but i would like the cell to be blank until S, I or R are entered into G4 and I4. At the moment it states Fail.

```
=IF(OR(AND(G4="S", I4="S"), AND(G4="R", I4="R"), AND(G4="I",I4="I")), "Pass", "Fail")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just change `"Fail"` to `""` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If anything but `S`,`I`, or `R` is in those two cells this will return an empty string:

```
=IF(AND(OR(G4={"S","I","R"}),OR(I4={"S","I","R"})),...,"")
```

Where `...` is your formula.

If all you care about is whether blank or not in those two cells it can be:

```
=IF(AND(G4<>"",F4<>""),...,"")
```

---

We can also use `SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS())` to lessen the use of `OR`s and `AND`s:

```
IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(G4,{"S","I","R"},I4,{"S","I","R"})),"PASS","FAIL")
```

Though this approach does not shorten the current formula greatly, it would if the criteria were to increase to more than 3.

So:

```
=IF(AND(OR(G4={"S","I","R"}),OR(I4={"S","I","R"})),IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(G4,{"S","I","R"},I4,{"S","I","R"})),"PASS","FAIL"),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the last one using SUMPRODUCT does exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: If this worked for you then please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.